# Classification of simple Lie algebras over finite fields

Tags: lie-algebras, finite-fields, positive-characteristic, restricted-lie-algebras

Classification of simple (or simple-restricted) Lie algebras over algebraically closed fields in positive characteristic is studied for a long time. Today, we know all finite-dimensional simple (or simple-restricted) Lie algebras over algebraically closed fields of characteristic $p \ge 5$. But, how about over **finite fields**? I don't know either the results of classifications over finite fields or some examples. Does anyone know some references?

Comment: [Theresia Nolte's diploma thesis (*Lie-p-Algebren und die Berechnung ihrer p-Darstellungen*)](https://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gerhard.Hiss/Students/DiplomarbeitNolte.pdf) might be of use.

Comment: In a sense, the first step is precisely the classification over algebraically closed field (of the same characteristic). This essentially yields the classification "up to tensoring with an algebraic closure". The second step could then be to compute the Galois cohomology to classify forms over finite fields.

Comment: @YCor's suggestion is carried out for the classical simple Lie algebras over finite fields of characteristic $\neq 2,3$ in section IV.6 of Seligman's 1967 book "Modular Lie Algebras." Chapter IV is "Forms of the Classical Lie Algebras" and section IV.6 is titled "Finite fields." Later chapters also cover some classification questions for certain nonclassical simple Lie algebras that arise in the positive characteristic case. Good book, but 55 years old, and presumably by now there is a more up-to-date reference.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0601380

Comment: Name of @KonradWaldorf's [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/415096/classification-of-simple-lie-algebras-over-finite-fields#comment1064635_415096):  [Premet and Strade - Classification of finite dimensional simple Lie algebras in prime characteristics](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0601380).  But that seems to be over algebraically closed fields, right?, whereas the question is specifically about non-algebraically closed fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The classification of simple finite-dimensional Lie algebras over finite fields is a very hard task and only few results are known. However, I suggest to have a look at the following paper by Bettina Eick and references therein: [Some new simple Lie algebras in characteristic 2](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jsc.2010.05.003).

Comment: Is it "very hard" over general finite fields, or specifically in characteristic 2 and maybe 3?

Comment: In my opinion this is a difficult problem in general. For instance, it is even unknown whether a finite-dimensional Lie algebra over a finite field contains a Cartan subalgebra in general.

Comment: What if "simple" is replaced with "absolutely simple"?

Comment: Of course, in characteristic $p>3$, in this case the problem is determining the forms of the simple Lie algebras, which are known by the Block-Wilson-Strade-Premet classification.

Comment: Until I couldn't watch the internet, many opinions suggested, thanks! I first asked this question because I thought that how the classification problems need a property of **base fields**.  I should be careful that some elementary properties such as the existence of Cartan subalgebras. But modular theory seems to be interesting:)